# Digamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Does $$\psi(z)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^{-t}}{t}-\frac{e^{-zt}}{1-e^{-t}}\right) dt$$ converges for $\Re{z}>0$?

Comment: It is unclear what the "psi gamma function" is.  The similarly named "[digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)" is frequently denoted using the symbol $\psi$ as $\psi(z)$.  A generalization is the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) also frequently denoted using $\psi$, as $\psi^{(m)}(z)$.

Comment: Yes for this function I meant. So is the digamma function convergent for $Re(z)>0$?

Comment: Functions aren't "convergent".  Sums, products, integrals, and other iterative/recursive operations are convergent.  Are you asking whether the domain of the digamma function includes the halfplane $\Re(x) > 0$ or are you asking if a particular sum, product, integral, or other representation of digamma on part of its domain converges on the right halfplane?

Comment: The integral representation.

Comment: *Which* integral representation.  There is no integral in your Question.  The Wikipedia lists several integral representations for digamma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Integral_representations .  MathWorld gives at least one more.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html  And the DLMF has a few as well.  https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9

Comment: $\psi(z)=\int_0^{\infty}(\frac{e^{-t}}{t}-\frac{e^{-zt}}{1-e^{-t}})dt$

Comment: You should edit the correct name of the function and the integral into your Question so that it accurately captures your question.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3504675) might address your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Gauss's integral representation of the digamma function is widely documented to converge on the (open) right halfplane.

- At the DLMF, 5.9.12: https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9#E12 , with the condition appearing immediately previously.
- At the Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Integral_representations , with the condition in the text, "If the real part of $z$ is positive...".
- In Abramowitz and Stegun, *Handbook of Mathematical Functions*, 6.3.21 : http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm

Comment: Thnx @EricTowers

Answer (score 0):

**Convergence at $0$:**
$$
\lim_{t \to 0}\left(\frac{e^{-t}}{t}-\frac{e^{-zt}}{1-e^{-t}}\right) = z - \frac{3}{2}
$$
so the apparent discontinuity at $t=0$ is removable.

**Convergence at $\infty$:**
Two parts,
$$
\frac{e^{-t}}{t} < e^{-t}\quad \text{and}\quad \int^\infty e^{-t} dt\quad \text{converges, so}\quad \int^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t}\quad\text{converges.}
$$
Also
$$
\frac{e^{-zt}}{1-e^{-t}} \sim e^{-zt}\quad\text{as } t \to +\infty
$$
But
$$
\int e^{-zt} dt = \frac{e^{-zt}}{z}
\tag1$$
Now
$$
\left|e^{-zt}\right| = e^{\mathrm{Re}\;(-zt)}
$$
So
$$\text{if}\quad\mathrm{Re}\;z > 0, \quad\text{then}\quad |e^{-zt}| \to 0 \quad\text{so}\quad \int^\infty |e^{-zt}|dt \quad\text{converges and thus}\quad \int^\infty\frac{e^{-zt}}{1-e^{-t}}\;dt \quad\text{converges.}
$$

On the other hand,
$$
\text{if}\quad \mathrm{Re}\;z \le 1,\quad\text{then}\quad
|e^{-zt}| \ge 1
$$

fortunately, the OP does not ask for this part.  Absolute convergence fails, but conditional convergence may hold anyway.